# Why does this size of module created by Android studio is too big?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I use Android Studio to create the simplest module "hello world", after running it, I found the size of the module directory is up to 10.6MB.  However, the size of the module I import from elsewhere is smaller than it.

Screenshot 1:
[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have build folder inside it. You can delete that one when you are transferring your module.

To make your apk file smaller you can put this in your gradle.build file.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'am a beginner,and I still have a problem.The apk size is also bigger then others. why other apk file can be only several hundred KB,however my apk is up to 1.2M and is only contain one class file?and are there any methods can   decrease the apk size?